# AWS Cognito User Pool : Given an App client id, how to get its Pool Id?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We have multiple cognito user pools.

The information from these pools are stored in a single master table and includes the `cognito user id` and `app client id` (highlighted below):
[image]
[image]

Using these two values, is there a way to figure out the cognito user pool id the user belongs to?

The cognito user pool id is required by the app we're developing.
Any information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly sure there is no cognito-idp call you can use to get a pool from either a client or a user id.

You could use `cognito-idp list-user-pools` followed by `cognito-idp list-user-pool-clients` for each pool, to find all the clients, and then update your master table with that info.

Comment: thank you, I found the similar answer after googling as well.